# undefined vue variable when executing db.each

Tags: sqlite, vue.js, electron

i'm learning with electronjs and sqlite3 and i used vue too, when i tried to to do tb.push in db.each the message was "undefined this.tb", i could fix it with no understanding how

so why the code below works

```
var app=new Vue({
el:'#resultDiv',
data:{
    message:'hi',
    tb:[],
},
mounted(){
    var tb=[];
    var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
    var db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');
    db.serialize(function() {
        db.run("CREATE TABLE lorem (info TEXT)");

        var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)");
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            stmt.run("Ipsum " + i);
        }
        stmt.finalize();
        var textee;
        db.each("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem", function(err, row) {
            textee=row.id + ": " + row.info;
            console.log(textee);
            tb.push(textee);
        });
    });
    db.close();
    this.tb=tb;
}
});
```

but this below does not

```
    var app=new Vue({
    el:'#resultDiv',
    data:{
    message:'hi',
    tb:[],
   },
   mounted(){
    var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
    var db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');
    db.serialize(function() {
        db.run("CREATE TABLE lorem (info TEXT)");

        var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)");
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            stmt.run("Ipsum " + i);
        }
        stmt.finalize();
        var textee;
        db.each("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem", function(err, row) {
            textee=row.id + ": " + row.info;
            console.log(textee);
            this.tb.push(textee);//this not working
        });
    });
    db.close();
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in your non-working example

```
db.each("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem", function(err, row) {
  textee=row.id + ": " + row.info;
  console.log(textee);
  this.tb.push(textee);//this not working
});
```

the keyword `this` doesn't refer to the vue component, but to the execution context of the `each`-function.

This is caused by using the `function() {}`-way of describing anonymous functions.

If you'd instead use the arrow-function way to express the callback:

```
db.serialize(() => {
  db.each("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem", (err, row) => {
    textee=row.id + ": " + row.info;
    console.log(textee);
    this.tb.push(textee);//this now working
  });
});
```

`this` now refers to your vue component's execution context and your code should work. Note that I had to use arrow function expression's for the `serialize`-function as well, otherwise `this` would have referred to that functions execution context instead.

#### Alternatives

If you, for some reason, cannot use the arrow function expression, you have several alternatives. You could explicitly bind `this` to the vue context like so:

```
db.serialize((function () {
  db.each(..., (function (err, row) {
    ...
  }).bind(this));
}).bind(this));
```

I don't particularly like this approach.

Or you could capture the `this` context in a variable under the closure of the mounted-method.

```
mounted() {
  var self = this;
  ...
  db.each("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem", function(err, row) {
    textee=row.id + ": " + row.info;
    console.log(textee);
    self.tb.push(textee);
  });
}
```

Comment: it works, now i have an other probleme, this <a href="page.html">page</a> open the page in browser

Comment: @RedaAli It's easier if you open a new question here on SO for that particular issue.